# MD5 is giving different results in PHP & JAVA

Tags: java, php, md5

In my Program, I load a file to my Server using Ftp out of a Java Program and then I compare the MD5-sum.

The upload works fine, and I get the same md5 sums. But the php-version has a "0" before the same md5-sum. Why is this so?

```
Php: 0e9e9399840d9a9368b53d3df98a6a2f
Java: e9e9399840d9a9368b53d3df98a6a2f
```

Comment: Those two stings are just hexadecimal representation of two 128-bit numbers. I think the difference is in conversion from byte array value to string. But both *numeric* values are identical (so `0e` is equal to just `e` in hexadecimal representation; `1110` in binary representation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're the same, it's just PHP has padded the value with an extra 0 in front so it's always 16 characters.

Think of the hash as a number in hexadecimal - it can be padded out so it's always the same number of digits (because it's never greater than 16 digits), but it doesn't have to be. It's a bit like comparing the numbers `209` and `0209`.

Comment: Thank you, then I can cut this '0' or is this always an important character?

Comment: Thanks. I always compare md5's as strings - I'll compare as hex numbers in future

Comment: In terms of data you can cut it - it's superfluous if you're comparing as hex numbers rather than strings (which you should be.) If you're comparing as strings then it's obviously important.